# How to iterate a multilevel dict in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json output which is in the form of a dictionary. While iterating over it I am not getting the values. What I am missing here?

Below is the sample json output of `dict` type. You can see there are two levels. So once I've reached `'level2'`, I then need to iterate over the next level which is not shown here as I have trimmed the data to one item.

```
data = {u'level1':
            {u'level2': [{u'Data':
                            {u'id': u'220',
                             u'byte': u'13',
                             u'time': u'1444',
                             u'ch': u'38'}}]}}
```

What I tried is as below:

```
d=[]
for x in data['level2']:
    d.append(x['Data']['id'])
```

Not sure why I am getting blank output.

Comment: `data` doesn't have a key `level2`. It does have `level1`, though, which has a value of a dictionary which itself contains a key `level2`.

Comment: Also, your literal for `data` is incomplete, missing a few `}` and `)`.

Comment: Try `for x in data['level1']['level2']:`

Comment: and data should look like `data={u'level1': {u'level2': [{u'Data': {u'id': u'220', u'byte': u'13', u'time': u'1444', u'ch': u'38'}}]}}`

Comment: yes.. that got trimmed while copying it should look like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you want to "iterate", especially since you trimmed down the data and didn't really specify what the output you wanted.

So here's a guess based on adding a little more sample data:

```
data = {u'level1':
            {u'level2': [{u'Data':
                            {u'id': u'220',
                             u'byte': u'13',
                             u'time': u'1444',
                             u'ch': u'38'}},
                         {u'Data':
                            {u'id': u'440',
                             u'byte': u'26',
                             u'time': u'2888',
                             u'ch': u'76'}}]}}

ids = []
for item in data['level1']['level2']:
    ids.append(item['Data']['id'])

print(ids)  # -> [u'220', u'440']
```

You could achieve the same result more concisely (with some loss of readability) by putting the `for` loop inside what is known as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
ids = [item['Data']['id'] for item in data['level1']['level2']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a recursive function like this:

```
def walkdict(data):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            walkdict(v)
        else:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Value for *level2* is a **list**. So, you have to traverse like this:

```
data={u'level1': {u'level2': [{u'Data': {u'id': u'220', u'byte': u'13', u'time': u'1444', u'ch': u'38'}}]}}
d = []
for x in data['level1']['level2']:
    d.append(x['Data']['id'])

>>> d
['220']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in data.items():
    p = v.get('level2')
    if p:
        print p['Data']['id']
```

maybe .